# Sql prepared statement not executing

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am using the following code to update my mysql table where both moving50 and moving200 are variable characters.

```
String sql = "update toplosers set Moving50 = ?, where Symbol = ?";  
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql); 
for(int i1=0;i1<i;i1++)
 {   

       stmt.setString(1, moving50[i1]); 
       stmt.setString(2,symbol[i1]);


    stmt.addBatch(); 
} 
stmt.executeBatch();  
}
```

I am getting "have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where Symbol = 'mysymbol'' at line 1
What is the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to add 'comma' for where clause.
Now check it.

```
String sql = "update toplosers set Moving50 = ? where Symbol = ?";  
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql); 
for(int i1=0;i1<i;i1++)
 {   

       stmt.setString(1, moving50[i1]); 
       stmt.setString(2,symbol[i1]);


    stmt.addBatch(); 
} 
stmt.executeBatch();  
}
```

see sample example [here](http://www.roseindia.net/jdbc/jdbc-mysql/UpdatesRecords.shtml)

Answer (score 2):

You have unexpected comma right after first parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid the comma character before the 'where' clause.